# Вывод результатов поиска в Wordpress по категориям постов

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! Прошу помощи,
Нужно сделать вывод результатов поиска в Wordpress по категориям постов и в каждой категории сортировка результатов по разному:

Persons: (результаты по категории постов "Persons", сортировка по релевантности)
1
2
3
pagination

Companies (результаты по категории постов "Companies", сортировка по релевантности)

News (результаты по категории постов "News", сортировка по дате (сначала новые)

Мой код (search.php) выводит по категориям но без сортировки. Результаты стремлюсь сделать кликабельными для перехода на соответствующий пост.

Что делаю не так?

```
'''
<?php
get_header();

// Get search visibility option from admin settings
$gecko_settings = GeckoConfigSettings::get_instance();

// Options page settings
$full_width_layout = $gecko_settings->get_option('opt_search_full_width_layout', 0);
// $builder_friendly_layout = get_post_meta(get_proper_ID(), 'gecko-page-builde-friendly', true);

$main_class = 'both';

if ($gecko_settings->get_option('opt_sidebar_left_search_vis', 1) == 1) {
    $main_class = 'main--left';
}

if ($gecko_settings->get_option('opt_sidebar_right_search_vis', 1) == 1) {
    $main_class = 'main--right';
}


if ($gecko_settings->get_option('opt_sidebar_left_search_vis', 1) == 1 && $gecko_settings->get_option('opt_sidebar_right_search_vis', 1) == 1) {
    $main_class = 'main--both';
}


$content_id = "";


if ($gecko_settings->get_option('opt_search_grid', 0) == 1) {
    $content_id = "gecko-blog";
}
?>

<div id="main" class="main <?php echo $main_class;
if ($full_width_layout === 1):
    echo " main--full"; endif; ?>">
    <!-- ABOVE CONTENT WIDGETS -->
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/widgets/above-content'); ?>
    <!-- end: ABOVE CONTENT WIDGETS -->
    <div <?php if ($content_id): ?>id="<?php echo $content_id; ?>" <?php endif; ?> class="content">
        <?php
        if (function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb')) {
            if ($gecko_settings->get_option('opt_yoastseo_breadcrumbs', 1) == 1) {
                yoast_breadcrumb('<div id="breadcrumbs" class="gc-breadcrumbs">', '</div>');
            }
        }
        ?>
        
        <?php
        // Group search results by category
        $search_categories = array(
            'Persons' => array(),
            'Companies' => array(),
            'News' => array(),
        );

        if (have_posts()):
            while (have_posts()):
                the_post();
                $category = get_the_category();
                if (count($category) > 0) {
                    $category_name = $category[0]->cat_name;
                    if (array_key_exists($category_name, $search_categories)) {
                        $search_categories[$category_name][] = $post;
                    }
                }
            endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
        
        <?php if (count($search_categories['Persons']) > 0): ?>
            <h2>Persons:</h2>
            <ol>
                <?php 
                // Sort Persons results by relevance
                uasort($search_categories['Persons'], function ($a, $b) {
                    $relevance_a = get_post_meta($a->ID, 'relevance', true);
                    $relevance_b = get_post_meta($b->ID, 'relevance', true);
                    if ($relevance_a == $relevance_b) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    return ($relevance_a > $relevance_b) ? -1 : 1;
                });
                foreach ($search_categories['Persons'] as $post): ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
            <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if (count($search_categories['Companies']) > 0): ?>
            <h2>Companies:</h2>
            <ol>
                <?php 
                // Sort Companies results by relevance
                uasort($search_categories['Companies'], function ($a, $b) {
                    $relevance_a = get_post_meta($a->ID, 'relevance', true);
                    $relevance_b = get_post_meta($b->ID, 'relevance', true);
                    if ($relevance_a == $relevance_b) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    return ($relevance_a > $relevance_b) ? -1 : 1;
                });
                foreach ($search_categories['Companies'] as $post): ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
            <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if (count($search_categories['News']) > 0): ?>
            <?php
            // Sort News results by date (newest first)
            usort($search_categories['News'], function ($a, $b) {
                $time_a = strtotime($a->post_date);
                $time_b = strtotime($b->post_date);
                if ($time_a == $time_b) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return ($time_a > $time_b) ? -1 : 1;
            });
            ?>
            <h2>News:</h2>
            <ol>
                <?php foreach ($search_categories['News'] as $post): ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
            <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        if (!have_posts()):
            get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
    <!-- UNDER CONTENT WIDGETS -->
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/widgets/under-content'); ?>
    <!-- end: UNDER CONTENT WIDGETS -->
```

'''

Comment: Как минимум `uasort()` не будет работать с пагинацией, так как Вы сортируете записи с той конкретной страницы на которой находитесь. Модифицироваться должен сам поисковой запрос. Но с этой Вашей идеей разделения по категориям, все не очень ясно.